# permalinks in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks

I just moved my wordpress blog from one host to another but permalink is giving trouble. Other than the homepage, other pages give a page not found error.

I edited the htaccess as per instructions

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /projects/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wdmgroup/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I even tried deleting the htaccess and rewriting but to no avail.

P.S : htaccess and Mod Rewriteare both enabled in Apache's conf

Regards,
Loveleen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Everything else was tried but still it didnt work. Later i realized that I had to make a Virtual DIrectory in apache for folder wdmgroup which I had directly placed inside the www folder.

Answer (score 3):

Delete .htaccess and reset permalinks from within Admin at Dashboard>>Settings>>Permalinks to be sure permalinks are set in the database as well as in the .htaccess file that WP generates.

Be sure WP is in /wdmgroup/ , because that's where it should be located, according to your .htaccess.

If you're moving WP to root, see [Moving WordPress « WordPress Codex.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)

Answer (score 1):

According to your .htaccess file, your site should be in the `http://www.site.com/projects/wdmgroup/` - folder. Is it so? Also, have you update needed entries in the `wp_options` table in your database?

Answer (score 0):

Check your apache configuration and verify that for the directory in which you store your Wordpress installation you have following settings enabled (probably you will have more configuration options for the specific directory, but these are the minimum required for Wordpress fancy permalinks):

```
<Directory var/www/>
FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```